# Rate and Ratio Problem

Tags: ratio

This is a question that is supplementary to my course work and is not required for marks. I find that it goes a bit beyond the scope of the material covered compared to the other questions. I understand the basics of rate and ratio but am struggling to equate the two ratios.

> A machine has two gears that rotate at constant speeds. Every hour,
> Gear A completes exactly  2  more revolutions than Gear B. After some
> time, Gear A has completed  60  revolutions, and Gear B has completed
> 50  revolutions. How many revolutions does Gear A complete in one
> hour?

This is the source: https://courseware.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/42/assignments/1104/

The given answer is 12.

My friend gave me the following answer which I understand is correct, am wondering if this is the "traditional" way to solve it, or if anyone has any other insights. How would you have solved it?

b/b+2 = 50/60.

Also, could this be solved not as a ratio problem but as a linear equation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let Gear $A$ complete $a$ revolutions in an hour.
Let Gear $B$ complete $b$ revolutions in an hour.
Let the amount of hours elapsed be $t$.

Hence, we have

$$a = b + 2$$
$$at = 60, \, bt = 50$$
$$\therefore (b + 2)t = bt + 2t = 60, bt = 50$$
$$\therefore 50 + 2t = 60 \implies t = 5 \implies a = 12$$